# Can not find partial view MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have spent much time to deal with partial view in mvc. Actually, I found many  answers to resolve this problem. However, these solutions did not work in my situation. Obviously, I used the code below to find partial view in controller but it returned "View not found". I don't know how to tackle this problem.

This code do not work properly :

```
var result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, "~/View/Home/HelloPartial.cshtml");
```

Below is my mvc action

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, "~/View/Home/HelloPartial.cshtml");
            var msg = string.Empty;
            if (result == null || result.View == null)
            {
                msg = "View not found";
            }
            else msg = result.View.ToString();

            ViewBag.Msg = msg;
        return View();
        }
```

Attached screen shots of demo project:

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are your trying to do with this code? And its `Views` (plural), not `View`

Comment: @StephenMuecke. Thanks for your modification. Certainly, I would convert a specified partial view "HelloPartial.cshtml" into string so firstly I found my partial views but this returned me NULL

Comment: @StephenMuecke I made mistake on spelling. Thanks so much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replace the line:

```
var result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, "~/View/Home/HelloPartial.cshtml");
```

With:

```
var result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, "~/Views/Home/HelloPartial.cshtml");
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This saved the day.

Comment: You do not answer typos - you vote to close them - this is of no use to anyone else!